# Converting letters into numbers

Tags: c#, numbers

What i'm trying to get is this:
Lets say A=6, B=12, C=18, D=24, so on till the Z..

Got a list of words and I want to get numerical value of every word printed on a text file.

How do I make the words become numbers?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Consider writing a Dictionary that maps a number to every letter.

Comment: _I want a [packet of Tim Tams that never runs out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoggSVxghWs)_ . Welcome to SO. Please don't post requirements and like Tim Tims, expect code to magically appear. Any code to show? What research have you done? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Characters are ordinal as are their numeric character codes:

```
foreach (char c in "ABCD")
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", c, (c - 65) * 6 + 6);

A, 6
B, 12
C, 18
D, 24
Z, 156
```

Answer (score 0):

First, one could implement a function to map the individual characters to numbers as follows.

```
int MapToNumber(char c)
{
    // your code
}
```

Then, one could use a function which maps strings to the sum of its characers, where Linq could be used.

```
int MapToNumber(string s)
{
    return s.Select(MapToNumber).Sum();
}
```

Finally, given a collection of strings, the output cold be done as follows.

```
foreach(string s in StringCollection)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", s, MapToNumber(s)));
```